# Magento 2 : Composer runs out of memory

Tags: magento2, php, composer, server-setup, ssh

I am trying to install instamojo payment gateway to my magento2 store, as per the instructions givne by instamojo page https://docs.instamojo.com/page/instamojo-integeration-for-magento-2

i tried the command using CLI (ssh) at my ubuntu host

```
composer update instamojo/instamojo-magento-2
```

> Loading composer repositories with package information
>
> Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
>
> Killed

I searched Google and found that , it happens because composer runs out of memory, but how could i increase the memory at remote server (I am running the website on live server at Godaddy)

Is there any other way of doing this ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this with more memory

```
php -d memory_limit=4G /usr/local/bin/composer update
```

OR

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 /usr/local/bin/composer update
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try something like this too:

```
php -d memory_limit=512M /usr/local/bin/composer update
```

Where /usr/local/bin/composer is the path where your composer is installed. And 512M is yor memory limit.

Comment: php -d memory_limit=-1M /opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer update instamojo/instamojo-magento-2 i tried again, and got message "Killed

Answer (score 0):

If composer runs out of memory, you'll have to increase memory limit for php , you can locate your php.ini by executing  following command in your ssh terminal ;

```
 php -i | grep  "Configuration File (php.ini) Path"
```

Open up the ini file , search and increase value for `memory_limit` until error resolves or you can set value to **-1** to remove memory limit.

Note that you must restart apache/nginx service after your change php configuration.

**EDIT :**

Try following command ;

```
php -r "readfile('getcomposer.org/installer');"; | php
```

Comment: but its have shared hosting, cant restart server .. any idea ?

Comment: check edit and see if it works for you.

Comment: sorry, i just copied that command.. nothing worked   error syntax error near unexpected token `|'

Comment: check out this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36107400/composer-update-memory-limit

Comment: php -d memory_limit=-1M /opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer update instamojo/instamojo-magento-2      i tried again, and got message "Killed"

Comment: Try php -d memory_limit=-1 /opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer update instamojo/instamojo-magento-2  , there should be no 'M'

Answer (score 0):

Try below command:

> `php -d memory_limit=4G composer update`